# Encoding an array for url in PHP

Tags: php, json, encoding, base64, ascii85

I have been working on some QR codes, I need to pass an array to the QR with the data but it needs encoding. The data itself is a `json_array` which is used to generate a PDF.

If I use `base64` encoding the QR code is stupidly large, and when using `ascii85` it breaks the QR.

Can you let me know of any encoding praticies which would work in the url, the shorted the coding the `betetr. qr_generator.php?data={encoded_json_array}`

Comment: try converting that to php array and using `serialize`

Comment: Already tried that method. Base64 is the best so far but its over sized.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

`urlencode($string);`

It encodes a string to be appended as an url parameter. So if you have an array, try:

`urlencode(json_encode($array);`

Comment: Has the same effect as the base64, the string is too large.

Comment: You can't really encode the string to be a lot less in size, unless you accept all unicode characters in you url (which you don't want for security reasons). You could also store the information in a session along with a random key and put that key in the url